# Vb.net form freezes after time

Tags: vb.net

So right after startup I hide the main form and open another form for license agreement.
(Its a simple form with text that you agree to use the program with an agree button that hides the agreement form and shows the main form if you)

If you don't click at that new form or press the "okay" button after 10 seconds it just freezes the whole program and if you try to close it then it has this loading mouse circle and results in a program that response crash. Also cpu usage gets down to 0.

Thats all the code in it so nothing big or smth that would freeze it:

```
Private Sub info_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Close()
    Main.Show()
End Sub
```

End Class

I've debugged it but idk why it freezes after time.
[debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl2fU.png)

Comment: you need to show main form first and close first form after that. Thats my best guess.

Comment: Alternatively you can me.hide() first form so it does not prevent further execution.

Comment: Is "Button1" the "OK" button? There's nothing else in the code? This makes no sense, there must be more code for it to find room to freeze _without you doing anything_. Post what you have if you have more.

Comment: no thats all, thats why i wonder ^^. yes the ok button closes it. also yes i have me.hide() already.

Comment: If you already have `Me.Hide()`, then you have more code than in your posted question. Please show all the code that involves the main form instantiation.

Comment: Sorry thats not possible since it has 3000 linse of code ^^. Well found the issue.

Comment: You are going about this is completely the wrong way. What you should be doing is handling the `Startup` event of the application and showing your license agreement there. This happens before the startup form is even created. If you do nothing when that form closes then the application will startup normally, displaying your main form. If the user rejects the license agreement then you cancel the event, i.e. set `e.Cancel` to `True`, and the app will quit without ever creating the startup form.

Comment: Further to that, you should display the license agreement by calling `ShowDialog` and it should return a `DialogResult` of `OK` if the user agrees and `Cancel` if they reject it. You can then just do this in the `Startup` event handler: `e.Cancel = (LicenseAgreementDialogue.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel)`.

Comment: showing the license agreement is handled in startup btw. i won't do showdialog since it looks ugly and the form i made has some design

Answer (score -1):

Not sure this is related to your issue but consider this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Close()
    Main.Show()
End Sub
```

`Me.Close()` means close the form, but right after you are still executing another line: `Main.Show()` to show the other (hidden) form. But you are running this code from a form instance that is being disposed. Depending on how fast the process goes this could cause problems. You could just swap these two statements. Make the other form visible again, then shut down the form. There should be no perceptible delay since the hidden form is already loaded in memory.

Make sure that you are not ignoring/swallowing exceptions. Maybe there is an error taking place but you don't see it.

Another question: that license agreement form, is it **modal** or not ?